# Excel disables addins on open

Tags: excel, vba

I made an Add-In for multiple users, I placed the `.xlam` file in the `XLstart` map of each user. But with one of the users, it's not working properly. When Excel is opening it blocks the Add-In, the macro's in the Add-In isn't showing anymore in the Visual Basic editor.

Does anyone know any solutions?

Comment: Are macros disabled on that machine?

Comment: And then `File | options | Add-Ins | manage Dropdown | Disabled Items` Enable the Add-In if it is disabled.

Comment: @braX, no Addins are not disabled.

Comment: @SiddharthRout its not disabled there aswell.

Comment: `When Excel is opening it blocks the Add-In` Do you get any kind of alerts?

Comment: @SiddharthRout no, I don't get any errors

Comment: Depending on how you put the add-in there, have you checked File - Properties in Explorer to see if you can unblock it there?

Answer (score 0):

For this issue you may to follow below steps:

1. Open Excel Options
2. Click on "Trust Center" tab
3. Click on "Trust Center Settings"
4. Now click on "Macro Settings" and Select "Enable all macros".

Your issue will be fixed.

Comment: That's the suggestion I made, and the OP said it was not the issue.

Comment: MP2103 thanks but indeed what braX said that's what I already tried.